# MS SQL оптимизация запроса

Tags: оптимизация, sql-server

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста с оптимизацией запроса
есть 2 таблицы

```
DOCUMENT([DOC_DATE], [SUM], [FIRM_ID])
```

и

```
FIRM([FIRM_ID], [NAME]), [ADDRESS])
```

сделал запрос:

```
SELECT @fr1 = '%' + RTRIM(@fr1) + '%';
SELECT YEAR(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE) AS YEAR,/* FIRM.NAME AS NAME, DOCUMENT.FIRM_ID,*/ SUM(January) AS January, SUM(February) AS February,
        SUM(March) AS March, SUM(April) AS April, SUM(May) AS May,
        SUM(June) AS June, SUM(July) AS July, SUM(August) AS August,
        SUM(September) AS September, SUM(October) AS October,
        SUM(November) AS November, SUM(December) AS December 
        /*into zz_job2*/ FROM
(select DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE, DOCUMENT.FIRM_ID,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=1  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as January,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=2  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as February,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=3  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as March,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=4  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as April,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=5  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as May,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=6  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as June,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=7  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as July,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=8  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as August,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=9  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as September,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=10  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as October,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=11  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as November,
case when (MONTH(DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE))=12  then DOCUMENT.SUM else 0 end as December 
from DOCUMENT) DOCUMENT 
INNER JOIN FIRM ON DOCUMENT.FIRM_ID = FIRM.FIRM_ID
where NAME like @fr1
group by DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE
```

Подскажите как его оптимизировать если таблица FIRMS содержит 150 000 записей, а табличка DOCUMENTS весит ~50 Gb

Comment: @Gena_2007, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если результаты нужны именно в таком виде - то альтернативы нет, хотя запрос стоит подрихтовать:

```
SELECT  YEAR(d.doc_date),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 1 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 2 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 3 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 4 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 6 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 6 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 7 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 8 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 9 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 10 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 11 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(d.doc_date) = 12 THEN d.sum ELSE 0 END)
FROM    document d
    JOIN firm f ON F.firm_id = d.firm_id
    WHERE [Name] LIKE @fr1
GROUP BY YEAR(d.doc_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то в духе

```
select sum([SUM]), extract (month from DOC_DATE) as Month
from DOCUMENTS
group by Month, FIRM_ID
inner join...
```

Возможно ещё, проблема в том, что в таблице DOCUMENTS значения SUM и FIRM_ID на жёстком диске перемешаны с содержимым собственно документов. Т.е. идут всего несколько байт нужных для выборки данных, потом много КБ содержимого документа, потом снова несколько байт... Тогда поможет индекс по SUM и FIRM_ID. Если и этого будет недостаточно, то смотрите в сторону OLAP

Comment: extract В Transact SQL такой функции нет

Comment: Разве в MSSQL есть функция extract? Кроме того в оригинальном запросе идет группировка по целой дате, а вы предлагаете группировать по месяцу и фирме - это же не одно и тоже.

Comment: Я хочу найти альтернативу case, какой вариант не могу ни как придумать

Comment: Хорошо, не EXTRACT, a DATEPART: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265%28v=sql.80%29.aspx. Я помнил, что что-то было, но первым нашлось EXTRACT.

Так именно что предлагаю группировать по месяцам т.к. ТС хочет именно это. Зачем извращаться с 12-ю полями!?